# How to get index position of values in python

Tags: python

I have a scenario , where I am trying to get index position of value

**My code :**

```
a_set = {22,56,26} 

print(a_set[56])
```

**Getting below error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

**Expected output :**

```
1   -> This the position of 56 from set
```

Comment: `set` is unordered so no notion of index. If you want order u need to use something like ordered set. https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/

Comment: @Epsi95 : Any way to get index position , if i want

Comment: when you are using set then normally you don't care about index, for example you want to search something at constant time, you use set, if you care about index, then I think you should start with list or tuple.

Comment: No it is unordered hence there is no index to determine the order

Comment: @Roman : How about converting the given set to List and getting its position

Comment: as others said, there is no index in `set`. in `list` or `tuple`, you can do `a_list.index(56)` or `a_tuple.index(56)`

Comment: @tabofo1420 That would work, but I would not count on it that the order is the same. if you like to do it that way try list(a_set).index(56)

Comment: If you print your set, you'll likely see your `{22,56,26}` actually already got re-"ordered" to `{56, 26, 22}`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is explaining a lot here: **sets in Python are not subscriptable**.
They dont have order relation.

According to your code example, you are trying to ask *weather a value exists in the set*, right?

In Python you can do it with `in` operator:

```
>> print(36 in a_set)
True
```

or

```
if (36 in a_set):
  my_function()
```

Answer (score -1):

Sets are by definition completely unordered and unindexed, you cannot get the information with an index directly as that is not what they were made for. As a workaround, you can simply convert the set to a list that is both indexed and ordered.

```
a_set = {22,56,26} 
print(list(a_set)[3]) # converts the set into and displays it's third entry.
```

To solve your problem, you can use .index() on the new list such as this:

```
a_set = {1,2,3}
print(list(a_set).index(1))
```